# New install problem

Tags: startup

I'm new to Ubuntu and just did what I thought was a successful installation.  After restarting the computer at the end, I get the message "1962: no operating system found".  Can someone help?  The computer is an older IBM desktop and had Windows XP installed originally.  I don"t think there are are partitions on the hard drive.

Thanks
Norm

Comment: does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/141879/error-1962-no-operating-system-found-after-installing-12-04-lenovo-thinkcentre

Comment: I can't help you further, but I can put you on the right track: The problem is that your BIOS can't find the OS. This can be because it is trying to boot the wrong disk, because the bootloader did not install correctly, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS may not be detecting your Hard disk. Try to boot into the BIOS and make sure the primary boot sequence is set to your primary hard disk(HDD).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered my question.  I checked the BIOS and it is set to boot the diskette first.  Could find no way to change this.  I put in another HDD and by tapping F12 after turning on, was able to get a menu that allowed me to start from CD-ROM drive.  The installation went well and the OS seems to be working fine.  Running a little slow but that could just be the machine and having never used Ubuntu before, I have no basis for comparison.

Thanks again,
Norm