# "No operating system found" - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot

"No operating system found" - Lenovo K450 / Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I have a Lenovo K450 Desktop (IdeaCentre)
BIOS date 29 October 2012

It came with Windows but I installed Ubuntu, wiping Windows.

Now running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for months. All fine till recently when for some unknown reason I started getting error messages when trying to update by both GUI method ("Software Updater" app) and via Terminal (sudo apt-get update).

I tried many ways of fixing this but was unsuccessful, so used a live Ubuntu 22.04 LTS USB stick to wipe the HDD clean and install fresh 22.04.

However, after installation, on booting I get "No operating system found".

In BIOS have tried changing from "Auto" to "Legacy" to "UEFI" - but, still get "No operating system found" each time I try to re-install 22.04.

I wonder if I destroyed the boot sector when wiping the HDD?
If so, I would have thought that a fresh installation from a live USB would have fixed this - but, clearly, has not.

I used the live USB to use GParted to look at the HDD and see that there is a problem with the MBR - the message it gives is this:
"Unable to read the contents of this file system!  Because of this some operations may be unavailable:  The cause might be a missing software package.  The following list of software packages is required for fat 32 file system support: dosfstools, mtools."

I checked and dosfstools was already installed, but mtools was not. I installed it by "sudo apt install mtools" and went through the whole process again - but still get "No operating system found".

I know there are similar problems posted recently, but these have not solved my specific problem. I should be VERY grateful for your help. Please note, I am 73 years old and not very technically adept, but do know how to use the Terminal if given explicit instructions.

## Thank you for your time - greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the BIOS settings have an UEFI boot order menu or an option to boot or trust an EFI file?

Comment: Please tell us 1) do you have data/partitions on the internal disk(*assuming only one*) that you care to preserve? ... 2) Please describe exactly the process that you did to wipe the HDD ... 3) Please describe exactly the process that you did to install Ubuntu ... 4) Please describe the process that leads to the message "No operating system found" ... And in detail please.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. This will take me a little time, but I will get back to you with the details you ask for - I am an old man so these things take me time! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: In BIOS -> Startup > Primary Boot Sequence - then under this heading, Options: CSM / Boot Mode / Quick Boot / Boot Up Num-Lok status / Keyboardless Operation / Rapid Boot.
Under "Boot Mode" the options are "Auto" or "UEFI only" or "Legacy Only".
I have tried all three options to no avail.

To answer your numbered questions:

1) I have no data partitions that I care to preserve - I have full back-up on an external HDD.

2 & 3) To wipe the HDD and install Ubuntu I used a live USB stick with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it - then selected the option to wipe the disk then install Ubuntu.

Comment: 4) After installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from the live USB stick and then booting up I get the message (in BIOS): "Error 1962: No operating system found. Press any key to repeat boot sequence." Then if I press any key, the Error 1962 message appears again - ad infinitum.

I hope this is the information you need?

Thank-you once again for your kind help.
=========================

Comment: OK ... As it seems, you did install Ubuntu the right way, but BIOS are not detecting your HDD ... I suspect it has something to do with "Quick Boot" or similar so try disabling those. and then turning your system completely off and then back on again.

Comment: Thank-you. Both Quick Boot and Rapid Boot options are disabled - still get Error 1962.

Comment: By the way, when I do a "lsblk" no drive with mbr found.

Comment: CSM is enabled.

Comment: Please see if this helps https://askubuntu.com/q/141879

Comment: Thanks Rafta - sadly that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM:
I used another live usb with an earlier version of Ubuntu on it - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

So, I am not sure what was corrected, either there is something wrong with the USB with Ubuntu-22.04 on it, or else there is a problem with the Ubuntu-22.04 iso.

I am now in the process of upgrading the 20.04 version to 22.04.